# Generating a key for brute force

Tags: java, ascii, brute-force

I am trying to decrypt a file via brute-force. I am only worried about the ASCII characters 32-127(All possible keyboard characters). The key needs to be a two character key. I am starting my for-loop like this:

```
    for(int i = 32; i < 128; i++){
        //Key is a string already declared further up.
        key = Character.toString((char) i);   
    }
```

I have printed that and it gives me all keys on the keyboard. I am stuck on how to make the two character string,

I have a few ideas in mind but they do not work. I thought about trying to just do something similar to this:

```
if(key.length() > 2)
     key = "";
else
     key += key(i);
```

but I think that will only give me characters that are "back-to-back" to each other.

I need to test for like 32 with 33-127 and so on and so for. Any insight would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to brute force this would be a nested for loop

```
for(int i = 32; i < 128; i++){
        //Key is a string already declared further up.
        for(int j = 32; j < 128; j++){
             key = Character.toString((char) i) + Character.toString((char) j);  

        }
    }
```

This says for every character, pair it with every character, so you would get all combinations of 2 character codes. You can do the checking right after you set the key

Comment: Ah I see, makes so much sense now that you pointed it out. Thank you, the answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try double for loop, something like this:

```
String key;
for(int i = 32; i < 128; i++){
    for(int j = 32; j < 128; j++){
        //Key is a string already declared further up.
        key = (char)i+""+(char)j;
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", " + key.length());
    }
}
```